# Can someone explain to me how the modulo character works to output a leading zero

Tags: c, modulo

This is the original question:
Create a function that displays all different combination of two digits between 00
and 99, listed by ascending order.

This was how a fellow student did it. It compiles. So all the first single digit outputs have to have a leading zero. I dont understand how he achieved it. Can someone explain to me this a%10 +0 part and how that works to print leading zeros? Thank you in advance.

```
 void   ft_print_comb2(void)
 {
int x;
int y;
enter code here
x = 0;
while (x < 99)
{
    y = x + 1;
    while (y < 100)
    {
        output_format(x, y);
        printlines(x, y);
        y++;
    }
    x++;
    }
}

void    output_format(int x, int y)
{
 if (!((x == 99 && y == 99) || (x == 0 && y == 1)))
 {
    write(1, ", ", 2);
    }
}

void    printlines(int x, int y)
{
char xmodule;
char xdiv;
char ymodule;
char ydiv;

xmodule = (x % 10 + '0');
xdiv = (x / 10 + '0');
ymodule = (y % 10 + '0');
ydiv = (y / 10 + '0');
write(1, &xdiv, 1);
write(1, &xmodule, 1);
write(1, " ", 1);
write(1, &ydiv, 1);
write(1, &ymodule, 1);
}
```

Comment: There are online compilers you could try yourself. And if your "friend" wrote it, why didn't he or she compile it?

Comment: `(x % 10 + '0')` means to take the remainder of `x/10` and turn that into an ASCII digit character. (Check the ASCII table!)

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, it is missing the needed `#include` statements .   Also, it is missing the needed prototype statements for `printlines()` and `output_format()`

Comment: OT: For ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently format the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Answer (score 1):

For numbers between 0 and 100, `x%10 + '0'` is the ASCII value of the lowest digit of `x`, and `x/10 + '0'` is the ASCII value[1] of the tens digit (or 0 if the number is less than 10). `'0'` is the ASCII value that represents the character 0, and `x%10` is the remainder when dividing `x` by 10. That's the trick used by your friend's code.

[footnote 1] (or more accurately, the character code from the character set of the execution environment which may or may not be ASCII).

However, the code written is quite complicated, and formatting numbers for output (including leading zeros) is provided by the standard library. Loops that range between two numbers can be conveniently described using a `for` loop. The function `write` used by the program is POSIX, and not part of the C standard library.

Here's a complete version using `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        for (int y = x+1; y < 100; y++) {
            if (y!=1) printf(", "); // skip comma for the first pair output.
            printf("%02d %02d", x, y);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x%10 + '0'` is the character code for the lowest decimal digit of `x` (if `x` is not negative). It is the code in the character encoding used by the C implementation. It is not necessarily the ASCII code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right. I added a footnote. (I already had limited the statement to numbers between 0 and 100, so your comment about negative numbers requires no edits).